# Entity Framework skipping Identity column Concurrency Check

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am working with Entity Framework 5 code-first and I have a situation where I have an entity which has an Identity column that is not part of the primary key.  When I add a new record and invoke `SaveChanges` on the context, I get a `ConcurrencyException`.  If I change the primary key on the entity map to `SCHED_ID` or remove `SCHED_ID` from the entity map altogether, `SaveChanges` completes without issue.  I suspect that since `SCHED_ID` is defined as an int, it defaults to a value of zero and Entity Framework thinks it has changed when the database actually assigns it a value (thus causing a `ConcurrencyException`).  Am I correct in my assumption? How can I work around this without changing the key on the entity map to `SCHED_ID`?

The entity is defined as follows:

```
public partial class Sched
{
    public int SCHED_ID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DATE_QUEUED { get; set; }
    public string STATUS_CODE { get; set; }
}

public class SchedMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Sched>
{
    public SchedMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.STATUS_CODE, t.DATE_QUEUED });

        //Properties
        this.Property(t => t.SCHED_ID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .IsConcurrencyToken(false);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Sched");
        this.Property(t => t.SCHED_ID).HasColumnName("SCHED_ID");
        this.Property(t => t.STATUS_CODE).HasColumnName("STATUS_CODE");
        this.Property(t => t.DATE_QUEUED).HasColumnName("DATE_QUEUED");
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SchedMap());
}
```

Comment: I think it's caused by the generated insert statement that filters by the PK instead of the scope_identity which could not be found because the transaction hasn't been committed. Can't you set the `SCHED_ID` as PK?

Comment: @YuliamChandra I certainly can, but that means my Map no longer matches the database.  If this is the right way to work around the problem then that is what I will do.

Comment: if you use EF6, you can intercept the query and replace the command text, that will probably work...