# Entity Framework read entity properties in SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5 code-first and I have overridden the `SaveChanges` method. In `SaveChanges`, I want to identify any entities with an `EntityState == EntityState.Added` (I can do this easily enough) however I then want to identify any columns in those entities which have been defined as a primary key, have their `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption` property set to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` and currently have `Null` value.

I need to identify these columns as my database currently has some columns defined as primary keys which need to be manually populated via code. I figured I could tackle this population of columns in `SaveChanges` on an insert but am stumped as to how to identify them.

How do I query column definitions in `SaveChanges`? I obviously know how to examine the data value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the data model, get the property that holds the primary key and see if it has the attribute you want. See an example here: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/entity-framework-metadata.
However, this will not work if you are not using attributes, but instead customizing the model in OnModelCreating.

Comment: Great blog post!  Is the EntityFramework metadata model documented somewhere? Your examples are a great illustration of how to get at the information I just don't necessarily know where to look for the HasDatabaseGeneratedOption property.  If I use your example extension method of GetIdProperties, I get the ID.  I am not customizing the model in `OnModelCreating`, but I am using a Map class to define what the entity looks like.  The entity map class sets the `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption`

Comment: Also, am I understanding you correctly that it is not possible to add a custom property (unless it is an Attribute on the entity itself) and read it out later?  Can it be an attribute on the Map Class and not the entity itself?

Comment: There isn't much documentation about that, I'm afraid. My solution works with mapping attributes; you can get the attribute from the id property using PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(). The attribute you want is DatabaseGeneratedAttribute.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897957/entityframework-identity-column-skip-concurrency-check